# How can I pass external variable in Excel macro for header?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm printing no of pages in right header (eg. Page 1 of [total no of pages]) I want to pass my variable after &P of &fcount(fcount is my variable). How can I pass this?

[image]

Comment: Where are you calculating `fcount` at the moment ? In another module/macro ?

Comment: in the same macro

Comment: .RightHeader = "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(10) & "&P of  &fcount"
        .LeftFooter = ""

Comment: Can you add your code to the question, so to see clearly what's happening ?

Comment: code is in vba the block where we post the code is not allowing me to do so

Comment: It's not clear in the comment, how your code is working. Maybe try posting a screenshot

Comment: With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = ""
        .CenterHeader = ""
        .RightHeader = "&P of  &N"

Comment: at the place of &N i want to pass my variable

Comment: See the Answer, I think it should work as far a I could understand your code

Comment: @mansisatpute Please don't post code as an image. [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
.LeftHeader = ""
.CenterHeader = ""
.RightHeader = "&P of " & focunt
```

This is working in My system.

[image: Working]

Comment: It is not working. it is printing only page 1 of  fcou

Comment: Then you need to paste the complete code, otherwise no one can see what's being passed in fcount.

Comment: Posted screenshot please check

Comment: As per screenshot your variable name is `focunt` not `fcount`. I have changed in the answer, I advise you to be careful with wordings when using a language. @mansisatpute

Comment: it is giving me file name after page number

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/workbooks-and-worksheets/formatting-and-vba-codes-for-headers-and-footers

Comment: @mansisatpute ... Try the amended version. It's working in my system now.

Comment: Office 365.. my Version